# Conditional dialogs in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I'd like to know if there is general solution, when I have parent form and there are two buttons, for example New and Edit.. now I don't want to create two separate dialogs, but rather determine wheter I clicked on one button or another and change text on buttons in dialog, functionalities and also passing some data from main form..

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single form, since *(most of the time)* Edit and New for same entity would require almost similar interface.

In that form define an overloaded constructor to receive parameters something like:

```
public MyForm() //for creating new record
{
}

public MyForm(int recordID) //For opening form with record based on the passed id
{
}
```

Now call the these constructors from their respective buttons.

On the form itself, you can modify the logic on save button to see if the form is opened with some particular ID or the record ID is null/0. Perform database operations (INSERT/UPDATE) accordingly.

Comment: Well this is genuinely simply solution I didn't think about, but it works like charm, thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an `enum` for the `form` and then do a `switch` statement for which mode.  For example;

```
public partial class UserForm : Form
{
    public enum UserFormMode {Edit, Add, Delete};
    private UserFormMode mode;
    public UserForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public UserFormMode Mode
    {
        get { return mode; }
        set
        {
            mode = value;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case UserFormMode.Add:
                // adjust your form
                break;
                case UserFormMode.Delete:
                // adjust your form
                break;
                case UserFormMode.Edit:
                // adjust your form
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Call from the Parent Form would include:

```
 UserForm dlg = new UserForm();
 dlg.Mode = UserForm.UserFormMode.Edit;
```